# What do fixed values for the coercivity and remanence of magnetic materials really mean?

Tags: magnetics, materials, hysteresis

I've recently found a table in a book that lists values for the coercivity and remanence of some magnetic materials, one value per material. As far as my understanding goes, the shape of a material's hysteresis loop is determined by the amplitude, frequency and waveform of the magnetic field strength of a field that the material is put into, and coercivity and remanence changes with these parameters (see [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266414487_The_influence_of_the_frequency_and_waveform_on_the_hysteresis_loop_of_some_NiZnCu_ferrites) paper for exmaple, especially pages 988 and 989).

So what do these values in the book really mean? Are these values for a sinusoidal field of a certain standardised frequency that saturates the material completely each half wave and thus "maximum" values of coercivity and remanence of said materials? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Coercivity is the hysteresis intersection with the magn. Field axis. Remanence is the intersection with the magnetization axis. These values are usually DC or maybe at the mains frequency (which is essentially DC)

Comment: Remenance is stored magnetic energy , a memory effect that may cause core saturation when started at peak voltage of opposite polarity of when it was opened if not done with sufficient margin

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I am aware of the meaning of the terms coercivity and remanence, the question centers more around the fact that the hysteresis loop of a given material can show different values of coercivity and remanence depending on the waveform, amplitude and frequency of the magnetic field that is used to magnetize the material when measuring its hysteresis loop, and why fixed values of remanence and coercivity are printed in books and material datasheets nevertheless. Is that unclear from the question itself, should I maybe edit it?

Comment: @tobalt  You said "These values are usually DC or maybe at the mains frequency". Can you by any chance point me to some literature / standards which would back this claim up? I guess you just had this information in mind without having a distinct source for it which is of course completely fine and a good hint for me, I am just asking because I would be interested in further reading regarding this topic. It seems very purposeful to refer to values measured at the mains frequency regarding transformer applications and such at least, but not for every kind of application.

Comment: @MS i have no concrete source and you are probably right that it varies by material and its intended use. When I characterized magnetic materials in the past for research it was done at DC since that is a point at which people should agree and where field strength is easily measured. For users it is more meaningful to know coercivity at the intended use frequency which can be much higher, e.g. for ferrites.

Comment: It depends on the interpolation of the Jiles-Atherton model for natural frequency where I expect like inductors at SRF L goes to 0, so you can interpolate the magnetic parameter from a fixed lower test f and the \$\omega _n\$